# Position absolute is not relative to its its parent CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created this loader, I want to place it in the center of its parent. So in the parent 
element I am using

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content:center;
```

but this is not working. Any help?

```css
.empty-container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.component-loader {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.loader-spinner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: -15px auto auto -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: calc(50% - 45px);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green #ccc #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: rotation .7s infinite linear;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```
<div style="height: 600px">
    <div class="empty-container"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="component-loader">
            <div class="loader-spinner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `centre` as a CSS value? Never seen that before. It's spelled with U.S. English -- `center`, not `centre`. Maybe if you correct that, your code will work?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as *simple typo*

Comment: @TemaniAfif, after correcting the typo, still its not working

Comment: remove the `top:150px`

Comment: You absolutely need to reduce all your code to the minimum that reproduces the problem the way you perceive it. Please remove all the animation, colors, fonts, sizes -- everything -- that still, according to you, shows you how your loader element isn't centered. It's otherwise impossible to tell what you have and what you mean by centering -- I see red borders, some margins here and there -- it's a mess! Also, post your reduced example as a *single HTML document*, with styling inside a `style` element. You'll then also learn if you created the problem while complicating your code.

Comment: @amn borders are provided to check for which I want to loader to be in center. Other div is provided to identify it more accurately,

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.empty-container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.component-loader{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.loader-spinner:before {
  content: "";
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green #ccc #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: rotation .7s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 600px">
  <div class="empty-container"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="component-loader">
      <div class="loader-spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you mentiion the changes as well

Comment: I make your container position relative and component-loader position set absolute. now as you set component-loader height and width 90px; i apply top, left, right and bottom values 0px; and apply margin: auto. it makes the component-loader block in center of height and width of your container because your container is relative.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.empty-container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}


.container {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;      
  position: relative;

}

.component-loader { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader-spinner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green #ccc #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: rotation .7s infinite linear;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 600px">

  <div class="empty-container"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="component-loader">
      <div class="loader-spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code, the parent element of your `.loader-spinner:before` is `.loader-spinner`.

```css
.empty-container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: centre;
  justify-content: centre;
}

.component-loader {
  position: relative;
}
.loader-spinner{
  position: relative;
   height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.loader-spinner:before {
  content: "";
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green #ccc #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: rotation .7s infinite linear;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 600px">

  <div class="empty-container"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="component-loader">
      <div class="loader-spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```